# Getting nullpointer exception in the last node of singlylinked list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

```
public class Node {
    public String name;
    public Node next;

    public Node(String name, Node next  ){
        this.name = name;
        this.next = next;

    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }
    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node n){
        next = n;
    }
    public String toString() {

       return "Name " + name;
    }
}

public class LinkedList {

    Node head = null;

    int nodeCount= 0;

    int counter = 0;

    LinkedList(){
         head = null;

    }
   public boolean isEmpty(){
       return  (head != null);
   }

    public void insertNode( String name ){

        if( head == null){
            head = new Node(name, null);
            nodeCount++;
        }else{
            Node temp = new Node(name, null);
            temp.next = head;
            head = temp;


            nodeCount++;
        }


    }
    public Node reverseTest(Node L){



          if(L == null || L.next ==null){
              return L;
          }

          Node remainingNode =  reverseTest(L.next);
          Node cur = remainingNode;
          while(cur.next !=null){
              cur=cur.next;
          }

          L.next = null;
          cur.next = L;

         return  remainingNode;

    }

    public boolean searchLinkedList(Node L, String S){
        if (L == null)
            return false;
        else{
            while(L !=null){
                if(S.equals(L.name))
                    return true;
                L= L.next;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String toString(){


        Node current = head;
        String output = "";
        while(current !=null){
            output += "[" + current.getName() + "]";

            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return  output;

    }


}

public class LinkedListDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        LinkedList FriendList = new LinkedList();

        FriendList.insertNode("First");
        FriendList.insertNode("Second");
        FriendList.insertNode("Third");
        FriendList.insertNode("Fourth");


       FriendList.searchLinkedList(FriendList.head, "Hello");

        String NameList = FriendList.toString();
        System.out.println(NameList);
        System.out.println("Finish");

    }
}
```

[image: NullPointerException]

I have a singly linked list. I wanted to search for a value that is not present in the linkedlist and in the last loop when it reaches L = L.next I receive NPE. I don't see what is the mistake here. Please point to the right direction.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just ran your code and it seems to have worked. Here's the output:

[Fourth][Third][Second][First]
Finish

Comment: I'm not into java much these days, but it looks like you're showing us a screenshot of your IDE's real-time variables... Do you get an exception or does it just show that? If you don't get an exception, it looks normal to me, and this reading is most likely taking place in the 'while' loop inside your search method.

Comment: @Kilazur It's the real-time variables. The program finishes. I was expecting not to see any of it. Am I incorrect? If that's the case then I feel like an idiot and apologize.

Comment: @ilaunchpad There's no problem :) I may still be mistaken, but I remember having had the same "problem" in my java days. So yeah, it's most likely just a reading, which is moreover correct, since it reads it when L is null... so obviously, trying to access its properties leads to a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comments, there is no errors. Your IDE is just showing you its last reading of these properties.

When you get to the last loop here:

```
public boolean searchLinkedList(Node L, String S){
    if (L == null)
        return false;
    else{
        while(L !=null){
            if(S.equals(L.name))
                return true;
            L= L.next;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

L is indeed equal to null; which means that when your IDE tries to read its properties (name and next), it (and only IT, not your program's actual output) gets a reasonable NullPointerException.

The program otherwise runs fine.